# Can I have variable value with @RepeatedTest annotation JUnit5

Tags: java, annotations, repeat, junit5

I have a test case where I have provided my test data in the form of enums. Like

```
enum TestTransactions {
    TestTransactions(Transaction T1, Transaction T2, String expectedOutput){}
}
```

In my Test class, I have to use it as:

```
class Test {
    private final static int REPETITION_COUNT = TestTransactions.values().length;

    @RepeatedTest(value=REPETITION_COUNT)
    private void testAllTransactions(RepetitionInfo info) {
        TestTransactions currentTest = TestTransactions.values()[info.getCurrentRepetition()];
        logger.info("Executing test for " + currentTest.name());

        setExpectationsFor(currentTest);
        whenControllerIsCalled();
        Assert.assertEquals(currentTest.getExpectedOutput(), result.getBody());
    }
}
```

Here this line `@RepeatedTest(value=REPETITION_COUNT)` is giving compilation error saying "Attribute value must be constant."

Is there any way to achieve this? Though I have tried assigning `REPETITION_COUNT (declared as final)` inside constructor and static block as well and during declaration as shown in this example.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your use case correctly, you want to use `@ParameterizedTest` with `@EnumSource` instead of `@RepatedTest` - this is how JUnit5 supports such use case out of the box.

First, add dependency on `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params` (which provides support for `@ParameterizedTest`) and then:

```
class Test {
    @ParameterizedTest
    @EnumSource
    void testAllTransactions(TestTransactions currentTest) {
        logger.info("Executing test for " + currentTest.name());

        setExpectationsFor(currentTest);
        whenControllerIsCalled();
        Assertions.assertEquals(currentTest.getExpectedOutput(), result.getBody());
    }
}
```

Also side notes for JUnit 5:

- `@Test` methods should be package-private (no visibility qualifier), not `private`
- use `Assertions` and not `Assert`

Answer (score 0):

What you’re experiencing is a constraint of the Java compiler. Unless the Java language specification will be changed you cannot do what you want.

What you could do is make a feature request for Jupiter to also accept a value provider, e.g. of type `Class<? extends Supplier<Integer>>`. Or you could simulate it using Jupiter‘s dynamic tests feature.